# Do my VisualStudio versions have to match on Windows and Mac for Xamarin?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I'm getting started with Xamarin. I have VisualStudio 2017 installed on a Windows 10 machine. I need to develop for both Android and iOS so I'm drafting requirements for the Mac I'm going to ask my boss to buy. If I ask for a Mac running VisualStudio 2019 for Mac (so it will more easily scale when we get around to upgrading to VisualStudio 2019 in Windows), will that pair  with a Windows machine running VisualStudio 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Strictly speaking only versions of the .Net framework need to match. Technically you don't even need to have a complete VS for the Mac for the connection to work.

But as the easiest way to connect is to have VS for the Mac you probably do want to match the versions.